# Unable to resolve build fail exception for Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle

I've recently started working on spring security tutorials given on github. I just downloaded zip and when I exported the projects in eclipse and tried "Build Model" it gave me exception message below.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
> Could not resolve com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.4.2.
  Required by:
      :buildSrc:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.4.2/appengine-tools-sdk-1.4.2.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authorization Required
   > Could not GET 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.4.2/appengine-tools-sdk-1.4.2.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authorization Required
   > Could not GET 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.4.2/appengine-tools-sdk-1.4.2.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authorization Required
```

With that I've just removed the proxy settings I've provided in eclipse network connections and in that case I'm not getting any such proxy authorization error, just that couldn't resolve thing.
If anyone has any idea what could be the cause ?

**build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'SpringSource Enterprise Release'
        url = 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'SpringSource Enterprise External'
        url = 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.4.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

> Proxy Authorization Required

message in your error string. You are likely need to configure your Internet connection proxy setrting. (e.g. in Internet Explorer -> Tool-> Internet Option)

Also generally it may make sense to check if mentioned versions of binaries are really on Maven Central with http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've already tried both of your suggestions. The Proxy Authorization Required disappeared once I updated Network Connection settings of eclipse and I've already checked for the dependencies availability on Maven Central.